# Eclipse deletes external JARs from build path when Gradle dependencies are refreshed

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have a problem with Eclipse: whenever I click Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project to refresh my Gradle dependencies, Eclipse deletes all of the external JARs in my build path. This happens with every Gradle project, and reinstalling Eclipse doesn't fix the problem.

The "Refresh Gradle Project" option:

[image: Refresh Gradle Project menu option]

Before and after refreshing:

[image: Before clicking Refresh Gradle Project]

[image: After clicking Refresh Gradle Project]

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that is the expected behavior: _Refresh Gradle Project_ resets the dependencies to the one specified in the `build.gradle` file. So it overwrites your manually made changes in the Java Build Path.

Comment: OK. Do I have to add the JAR files to my `build.gradle`, or is there another way?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In a Gradle project, do not directly change the Java Build Path settings. Change these settings inderectly by editing the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the expected behavior: *Refresh Gradle Project* **resets the dependencies to the ones specified in the `build.gradle` file**. So it overwrites your manually made changes in the Java Build Path.

In a Gradle project, instead of changing the Java Build Path settings directly, **add all dependencies via the `build.gradle` file**.

Answer (score 1):

I can not post comment yet.
Did you check the gradle setting for repo locations ?
Eclipse may not able to get the jars from the repo.
and also did you try

```
 gradle eclipse
```

to refresh the eclipse dependencies from command line, and refresh the project in eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The JARs are stored locally on my computer; they're not being retrieved from a repo. I tried `gradle eclipse`, and it just says `Task 'eclipse' not found`.

Comment: you need add the plugin :  

plugins {
    id 'eclipse'
}

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I found another way to fix the problem.